# What is the number after @ sign in debugger thread view in android studio

Tags: android-studio

[image]

What is the number after @ sign in debugger thread view. I doesn't seem to be the thread ID, source code line number or java object ID.

Comment: Is this a programming question? Is it an error?

Comment: No it's not an error, i added another image to make it clearer. I just want to know what the @3601 means.

Comment: I think that is the amount of thread that used to run the app

Comment: That makes no sense. Why's it different on each thread then?

Comment: Does it bother you? I think this is irrelevant information.

Comment: OK so you don't know. Anybody else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do the numbers in Android Studio debugger window mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52543967/what-do-the-numbers-in-android-studio-debugger-window-mean)

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be it. After all these years. Thanks. Not useing Android Studio at the moment though.